# Find the possible values of $p$ for which the equation has coincident roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Find the possible values of $p$ for which the equation $(2p+3)x^2+(4p-14)x+16p+1=0$ has coincident roots.

Coincident roots means 'equal roots'. For equal roots, we should use: $b^2-4ac=0$

$(4p-14)^2-4(2p+3)(16p+1)=0$

After solving this, I get: $-112p^2-536p+184=0$

I solved the above equation by this formula: $\frac{-b\pm \sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

Is this right? Maybe there is some mistake but I can't find it. My answers are wrong. I got $-5.11$, $0.32$, my book says: $\frac{1}{2}$, $-3\frac{2}{7}$. Help. :(

Comment: You are doing fine. Minor slip, the coefficient of $p$ should be $-312$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks! Let me try!

Comment: Divide through by $-8$. Don't even need Quadratic Formula, the thing factors nicely.

Comment: @AndréNicolas yeah, alright. It seemed bigger at first, now it's okay. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have $-112p^2 -312p + 184=0$

Answer (score 1):

If you expand the equation $$(4p-14)^2 - 4(2p+3)(16p+1)=0$$
you'll get $$16p² -112p +196 -128p² -200p -12 = 0$$

then, you'll get $$-112p² -312p +184$$

using the Quadratic Formula, you'll get:

$$\dfrac{1}{2}\quad\text{or}\quad-3\frac{2}{7}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

If it has coincident roots then $b^2-4ac = 0$
$$(4p-1)^2 - 4(2p+3)(16p+1) = 0$$
Expand and you get
$$14p^2 + 39p - 23 = 0$$
$$(2p-1)(7p+23) = 0$$
$$P = 1/2\quad\text{or}\quad P = -23/7$$